# Check Java Project for Android compatibility

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Within an Android project in Eclipse, code that is only available in certain API versions usually throws a warning for me.

I don't think non-android projects I am referencing from my Android project are being checked in this way.

This has caused some problems for me as I've accidentally used some functions not available on older versions of Android.

How do I check whether a non-android project is using Android API in a lower version than what I've targeted in my manifest?

Comment: I'm curious that what are these referenced projects using Android and not being Android projects? Some libraries?

Comment: @Niko Yes. I have a desktop and android applications which reference a shared project.  This shared project uses some functions available only on certain versions of Android.  I need to some kind of check on this shared project to get warnings about these functions.

Comment: Is it possible to make the referenced project an Android project and this way you get warnings for deprecations and then you add hooks for them to use the lower API?

Comment: Either what @Niko said or refactor the Android-related code in the shared library into another Android library project.

Comment: @Pedantic I can't make the referenced project an Android project as the Desktop app couldn't use it.  Refactoring the Android related code would work (in fact I already did that with more obvious pieces), but I have no way of automatically finding code that causes problems like this for refactoring.

Comment: Then you could remove all the Android code into an Android library project

Comment: I can't do that as then the desktop project couldn't use it.

Comment: I personally haven't looked into it, but why couldn't an Android library jar be referenced by a non-Android application (license and obvious SDK dependencies notwithstanding)?  It seems like you're already doing that.

Comment: If the desktop already uses the library which has Android code why cannot it use Android library jar too? Maybe you need to have two versions then of your referenced project, desktop one without Android code and then the Android version?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken about the desktop project not being able to reference an Android project, I'll try that now.

The desktop project does not reference any android code.  It references the shared Java project, which happens to use Android friendly names.  For example, NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress(). This function is available in both desktop java, and Android.  But in Android its only available in API level 9 and up.

Comment: I am not referencing any Android specific code from my desktop project.

Comment: Of course, we'd assume not.  But if the shared library references Android code there's not much of a difference between an Android library project and a standard shared library project.  Flipping that flag will get you the warnings you need about the deprecated code.

Comment: @Pedantic The shared library doesn't reference Android specific code.  It references only code common between desktop and Android. Hence the name shared. That's the difference.

Comment: But I was wrong, you can reference an Android project from a Desktop project, and it compiles.  So I can make it an Android project, and just keep it clean of Android specific code. If one of you posts an answer here I'd be happy to accept your solution.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison wait, wait.. you're question (I'm quoting it as it exists now is): `How do I check whether a non-android project is using Android API`  implies you are using Android API calls in your non-Android project.

Comment: Because technically I am... its just those Android API calls also happen to exist in Java Desktop API.  Get me? Sorry for your confusion, I could have worded that better.

Comment: @Pedantic if you want to post some of the valuable tips you offered here I'd be happy to upvote you too.  I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, as you said Niko nailed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the referenced project into Android project and this way you can get `Lint` warnings for deprecation and then do the needed refactoring to support different API levels.

Comment: Thanks Niko, nailed it.